# Create a new pandas DataFrame Column with a groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, pandas-groupby, vectorization

I have a dataframe and I'd like to group by a column value and then do a calculation to create a new column.  Below is the set up data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Red' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'Groups':['A','B','A','A','B','C','B','C','B','C'],
    'Blue':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
})
   
df.groupby('Groups').apply(print)
```

What I want to do is create a 'TOTAL' column in the original dataframe.  If it is the first record of the group 'TOTAL' gets a zero otherwise TOTAL will get the ['Blue'] at index subtracted by ['Red'] at index-1.

I tried to do this in a function below but it does not work.

```
def funct(group):
    count = 0
    lst = []
    for info in group:
        if count == 0:
            lst.append(0)
            count += 1
        else: 
            num = group.iloc[count]['Blue'] - group.iloc[count-1]['Red']
            lst.append(num)
            count += 1
    group['Total'] = lst
    return group

df = df.join(df.groupby('Groups').apply(funct))
```

The code works for the first group but then errors out.

The desired outcome is:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({
    'Red' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'Groups':['A','B','A','A','B','C','B','C','B','C'],
    'Blue':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
    'Total':[0,0,29,37,48,0,65,74,83,92]
})

df_final

df_final.groupby('Groups').apply(print)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each group, calculate the difference between `Blue` and shifted `Red` (Red at previous index):

```
df['Total'] = (df.groupby('Groups')
                 .apply(lambda g: g.Blue - g.Red.shift().fillna(g.Blue))
                 .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))

df

   Red Groups  Blue  Total
0    1      A    10    0.0
1    2      B    20    0.0
2    3      A    30   29.0
3    4      A    40   37.0
4    5      B    50   48.0
5    6      C    60    0.0
6    7      B    70   65.0
7    8      C    80   74.0
8    9      B    90   83.0
9   10      C   100   92.0
```

---

Or as @anky has commented, you can avoid `apply` by shifting `Red` column first:

```
df['Total'] = (df.Blue - df.Red.groupby(df.Groups).shift()).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

df
   Red Groups  Blue  Total
0    1      A    10      0
1    2      B    20      0
2    3      A    30     29
3    4      A    40     37
4    5      B    50     48
5    6      C    60      0
6    7      B    70     65
7    8      C    80     74
8    9      B    90     83
9   10      C   100     92
```

Comment: Thank you all I am going to dig into your answers!

Comment: unfortunately I have been unable to use this to solve my problem due to generalization.  Obviously this means I wrote the question poorly as the answers work.

Comment: Basically I want to feed in the two groupby colmuns apply a complex function and then update the column and then restore the original dataframe with the new column.

Comment: The problem with using a lambda is I can't get two seperate rows to execute the function.

Comment: unfortunately the question as I posed it is two simple and leaves open a subtraction work around.